# The effect of adding unique IDs on mobile apps performance

Tags: react-native, appium, performance-testing, mobile-application, unique-id

I'm working on a test automation project with Appium for the react-native mobile app, so I need accessibilityLabel for every element in each app's page, but our developer team says that adding accessibilityLabel for every element reduces performance, I want to know that is it true or not?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any mention in the official site (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibility) that this impact performance. Basically it is just turning "on" the accessible as true.

```
<TouchableOpacity
  accessible={true}
  accessibilityLabel="Go back"
  accessibilityHint="Navigates to the previous screen"
  onPress={this._onPress}
  >
   <View style={styles.button}>
     <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Back</Text>
   </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

If that is the concern of your team, one way is to make sure that parent components have their accessible attribute set to false; this allows the accessibility visibility of children to bubble up through a parent, rather than treating the parent component as a monolithic component from the perspective of the accessibility system.